# Angularjs performance when binding to deeply nested object attributes

Tags: javascript, performance, angularjs, data-binding

When data binding in Angularjs, is there a performance difference (significant or otherwise) between

`<div>{{bar}}</div>`

and

`<div>{{foo.bar}}</div>`?

What about `<div>{{foo.bar.baz.qux}}</div>`?

Context: I am on a team building a large Angularjs application that will potentially have a high volume of data flowing through it, and we would like to avoid the performance hit if there is one.

Comment: There is an interesting talk from Brian Ford about AngularJS with lots of data: https://github.com/btford/brian-talks-about-angular-with-lots-of-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As i know, the re-evaluation happens within a `digest`.
Angular iterates through all values in the scope and checks, if the value has changed.

It doesn't look like deep nesting causes much pains there, cuz it's just checking agains the value used in the view. (as long as you dont place a watcher on this deep nested object)

***But for some hints***:

**Don't** use methods for conditions within the view:

```
<span data-ng-hide="someFunction()"></span>
```

The function will be executed on each `digest` this may hurt.

**Don't** use watchers on top of a deep object structure:
Will recursivly run through the whole thing for re-evaluation --> hurts

**Use directives instead of `{{}}`**:

Why? Example: **angular-translate**: 
If provides a filter and a directive for the same thing.

```
<span>{{'WELCOME'|translate}}</span>
<span data-translate="'WELCOME'"></span>
```

The filter will be re-evaluated on every `digest`, while the directive has a watcher on that passed value and only re-evaluates, if this code does actually change.

**Use** `data-ng-if` **instead of** `ng-Show/Hide` (And since the `data-ng-if` is available):

`ng-Show/Hide` just makes the DOM elements disappear by using `display:none;` with css.
The hidden DOM elements will still be evaluated and the data changed, even if it's not visible.

`ng-if` will completely remove the DOM element, no re-evaluation for stuff within the `ng-if`